# Create new file in Blender 2.79

Tags: animation, blend-files

I'm an absolute beginner in Blender.

I installed Blender 2.79,  when I want to create a new 2D animation file I couldn't perform this task.

I googled a lot but I couldn't find where is the problem.

I'm using Windows 10 - 32bit

[image: Blender start screen]

[image: File-New]

[image: Confirmation after File-New]

Comment: 2.79 doesn't have templates in the New File dialog, it had Screen layouts instead (changing editors layouts within certain file). Opportunity to pick a file template while creating new file was added in 2.8x releases.

Answer (score 1):

That is normal behavior. Blender uses a template file, and to create a new document is to reload the template file. From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/info/file.html): "New (Ctrl-N): Clears the current scene and loads startup.blend."

Blender 2.79 is not the most recent release, and more recent releases of Blender have changed the phrasing of this menu option and it now gives a choice of templates.

The latest 2.9 release is available here: https://www.blender.org/download/
And the Long Term Support release of 2.83 is here: https://www.blender.org/download/lts/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

User slerfsterdn is not quite right as all you need to do is to leftclick on the screen right after you launch Blender and go to preset layouts, as shown below, to change the Default one.
[image]

Read Blender manual first to learn i.a. editors should you need any modifications. You can add custom layouts with the "+".